# How to make a database connection(psycopg2) to any consumer in kombu?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, kombu

I want to create three Kombu consumers, and every consumer has a connection to the database, and each connection is independent of the rest.

I want to replace the sentence "connection database of worker" in the task function, the connection of the consumer database that is in progress.

Thank you for helping me.

its my concumer:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

from kombu.mixins import ConsumerMixin
from kombu.log import get_logger
from kombu.utils import reprcall

from dashboard.rabbitmq import conf
from kombu import Exchange, Queue


logger = get_logger(__name__)


class Worker(ConsumerMixin):

    def __init__(self, connection):
        self.connection = connection

    def get_consumers(self, Consumer, channel):
        _list_consumer = []
        for item in range(0, 3):
            _list_consumer.append(
                Consumer(
                    queues=[Queue('viewer', Exchange('aghigh', type='direct'), routing_key='viewer')],
                    accept=['pickle', 'json'],
                    prefetch_count=1,
                    callbacks=[self.process_task]
                )
            )
        return _list_consumer

    def process_task(self, body, message):
        fun = body['fun']
        args = body['args']
        kwargs = body['kwargs']
        logger.info('Got task: %s', reprcall(fun.__name__, args, kwargs))
        try:
            fun(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            logger.error('task raised exception: %r', exc)
        message.ack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kombu import Connection

    with Connection(userid=conf.RABBIT_MQ_USER, password=conf.RABBIT_MQ_PASS) as conn:
        try:
            Worker(conn).run()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print('bye bye')
```

and my task:

```
def task(*args, **kwargs):
    print("Hello %s" % kwargs)
    conn = "connection database of worker"
    cur = conn.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO activity_activitystate (viewer_ip, activity_id, viewer_id, created_at) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s )", (
            kwargs['viewer_ip'],
            kwargs['activity_id'],
            kwargs['viewer_id'],
            kwargs['created_at'],
        ))

        cur.execute("UPDATE activity_activity SET view_count = view_count + 1 WHERE id = {0}".format(kwargs['activity_id']))

        conn.commit()
    except:
        pass

    cur.close()
```

this database connection setting:

```
from dashboard.singleton import Singleton
from dashboard.rabbitmq import conf
import psycopg2


@Singleton
class DbConnection(object):
    __co = None

    def __init__(self):
        if self.__co is None:
            __co = psycopg2.connect(
                host=conf.DATABASE['HOST'],
                database=conf.DATABASE['NAME'],
                user=conf.DATABASE['USER'],
                password=conf.DATABASE['PASSWORD']
            )

            self.__co = __co

    def get_connection(self):
        return self.__co


conn = DbConnection().get_connection()
```

Comment: Here is the relevant documentation for you [pyscopg2.connect](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/module.html#psycopg2.connect)

Comment: I know how to connect, but I want to do that for every consumer.

Comment: consumer.psycopg2.connect(
                host=conf.DATABASE['HOST'],
                database=conf.DATABASE['NAME'],
                user=conf.DATABASE['USER'],
                password=conf.DATABASE['PASSWORD']
            )